# RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Double but got scalar type Float for argument #2

Tags: python, pytorch, dtype

I have a `PyTorch` LSTM model and my `forward` function looks like:

```
    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        print('in forward', x.dtype, hidden[0].dtype, hidden[1].dtype)
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        return lstm_out, hidden
```

All of the `print` statements show `torch.float64`, which I believe is a double. So then why am I getting this issue?

I've cast to `double` in all of the relevant places already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure both your data and model are in `dtype` `double`.

For the model:

```
net = net.double()
```

For the data:

```
net(x.double())
```

It has been [discussed on PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-expected-object-of-scalar-type-double-but-got-scalar-type-float-for-argument-2-weight/38961/9).